# Premiere Pro CC: How to reset control panel group settings

Tags: premiere

I accidentally clicked on "loose panel group" in the mirror for creating a new title, but there is no button to fix them together again. I tried resetting the setting, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 'loose panel group' a free translation of whatever the option is labeled in whatever language you're using Premiere Pro in? Because I can't find an option or button that says exactly this ...

Anyway, you can change workspaces in the menu, click **Window** → **Workspaces** and select a workspace preset. If you want the default workspace back, make sure to select the **Assembly** preset (in Premiere Pro CC). If you want to revert any changes you made to the saved layout, select **Reset to Saved Layout** from the same submenu or press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: Yea, its just an inaccurate translation, because I have the programm on german and couldnt find the correct translation..
But yes, that's exactly the solution for my problem! Thanks a lot!